# What's Wrong With My Bike? Squeaking or Squealing Noises?

Tags: noise

I made a video of it so hopefully someone will watch it and help me out.

Comment: Does it do it when turning the cranks by hand with the rear wheel off the ground -> no load on the system.  Do you do regular maintenance?  You said it was 10 speed, does it still make the noise in the smaller front chainring?

Answer (score 1):

We can hear that it graunches in-time with your pedal strokes and as you noted, stops when coasting.   This eliminates anything in the rear wheel as a cause.

The sound is "dry tortured metal" and not a click or a squeak.

I suspect it is one of:

- Bottom bracket bearings have run out of grease.  This is my prime thought.  The cranks may have sideways/lateral motion that shouldn't exist. What happens if you pedal backward?
- Pedal axle bearings have run out of grease on one side - test by free-spinning each pedal and see if they do several turns under their own momentum.
- Crusty dry chain, either by itself or dragging through the front derailleur cage.
- Dirty rear hub/freewheel area - though this would cause slippage rather than the friction increases described.  Unlikely.